# how to get all the controller types from different assembly

Tags: c#, .net, validation, model-view-controller

I am implementing Custom Remote Validation, where I need to get all controllers and for that I have used the code:

```
Type controller = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
                .FirstOrDefault(type => type.Name.ToLower() == string.Format("{0}Controller",this.RouteData["controller"].ToString()).ToLower());
```

But, the problem is my controllers and viewModels are on two different assemblies so Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly() doesn't get any controller. The above code is in the assembly where i have a view model.
How can i get all the controllers from different assembly.

Comment: `Assembly.Load()`?

Comment: If you use ASP.NET Core then there's something like application parts that let you load controllers from different assembly.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/app-parts?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: I don't know for what purpose you want to get those types.

Comment: Konrad has a point... in which case then you are facing an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377). Another alternative to what Konrad is suggesting is [MEF](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bclteam/tag/MEF/)

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that your second assembly is referenced by the first one (the one holding your view model). You just need to get referenced assemblies and check if it is already loaded, if not then load it and then just call **GetTypes** as you have already done with your executing assembly. Here is a sketch:

```
var assemblies = executingAssembly.GetReferencedAssemblies();
var loadedAssemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().ToArray()();
foreach (var assemblyName in assemblies)
{
    var assembly = loadedAssemblies.FirstOrDefault(a => a.FullName == assemblyName.FullName) ??
                   AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(assemblyName);
    Type controller = assembly.GetTypes()
        .FirstOrDefault(type => type.Name.ToLower() == string.Format("{0}Controller",this.RouteData["controller"].ToString()).ToLower());
}
```